# What's wrong with my simplification of $\frac1i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, education

Supposedly, $\frac1i=-i$.
However, my simplification reaches another result:
$$\frac1i=\frac{\sqrt1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{\frac1{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}=i\text.$$
What's wrong with my process?

Comment: Well, I'd say it makes about as much sense as $1=\sqrt{1}=-1$.

Comment: This has been asked and answered here many times (with slight variations); here is the standard one: [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ is only guaranteed to be valid when $a,b$ are positive real numbers.

For complex numbers, all bets are off.