# Evaluating $\sin(\pi x)$ correctly using complex exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Clearly, one has $\sin(\pi x)\neq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$. But, one also has $\sin(\pi x)=\frac{e^{\imath\pi x}-e^{-\imath\pi x}}{2\imath}=\frac{(e^{\imath\pi})^x-(e^{-\imath\pi})^x}{2\imath}=\frac{(\cos(\pi)+\imath\sin(\pi))^x-(\cos(-\pi)+\imath\sin(-\pi))^x}{2\imath}=\frac{(-1+\imath0)^x-(-1-\imath0)^x}{2\imath}=\frac{(-1)^x-(-1)^x}{2\imath}=0$ seemingly for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $(\pm\imath)^2=-1$. With $x=0.5$, for example, one would then have $\sin(0.5\pi)=\frac{(-1)^{0.5}-(-1)^{0.5}}{2\imath}=\frac{\sqrt{\imath^2}-\sqrt{\imath^2}}{2\imath}=0$ rather than $\sin(0.5\pi)=\frac{\sqrt{-1} - \sqrt{-1}}{2\imath}=\frac{\sqrt{\imath^2} - \sqrt{(-\imath)^2}}{2\imath}=1$ (which is correct) while $\sin(0.5\pi)=\frac{\sqrt{-1} - \sqrt{-1}}{2\imath}=\frac{\sqrt{(-\imath)^2} - \sqrt{\imath^2}}{2\imath}=-1$. But how to decide when to take $-1=\imath^2$ or $-1=(-\imath)^2$, how do the sign of the arguments of $\cos$ and/or $\sin$ (in Euler's identity) relate to $(\pm\imath)^2=-1$ and how about $0\neq x\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $e^{i\pi x} = \left(e^{i\pi}\right)^x$ is not valid for real $x$, only integer.

Comment: It is NOT true in general that $e^{z_1z_2}=(e^{z_1})^{z_2}$

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-cdot-1-neq-sqrt-12) question states basically the exact same problem but in an easier way. As the helpful comments already wrote $e^{i\pi x}=(e^{i\pi})^x$ only if $x$ is an integer. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Relation_to_Euler%27s_formula) about "De Moivre's formula" might be interesting.

> De Moivre's formula does not hold for non-integer powers. The derivation of de Moivre's formula above involves a complex number raised to the integer power $n$. If a complex number is raised to a non-integer power, the result is multiple-valued.

This is because the complex logarithm is not a bijective funtion. An example: $e^{2i\pi}$ and $e^{4i\pi}$ are equal. Taking $\log$'s on both expressions yields $2\pi i=4\pi i$, which is false. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities) for more detail.

Comment: Side note that DeMoivre's Theorem may be alternatively derived by showing that $e^{i\alpha} \times e^{i\beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}.$  However, your analysis was on point, and the side note is not.

Comment: I'm sorry - what side note are you talking about?

Comment: First two words in my comment.  That although there is an alternative derivation of DeMoivre's Theorem, this alternate proof is not relevant to the point that you were making in your answer.

Comment: What point was I trying to make in my answer? I only said that the OP should look at that Wikipedia article, and then I quoted something, (without any derivations). Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Your point that $e^{i\pi x} = \left(e^{i\pi}\right)^x$ only if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Ah yes. But what's the problem here?

Comment: I wasn't criticisizing your answer **at all**.  I was simply indicating that your analysis focused on the derivation of DeMoivre's Theorem, as it pertains to raising $n$ to a positive integer.  So, your reasoning was certainly logical.  And so, not that it was relevant to the point that you were making, DeMoivre's Theorem can be derived in an alternative manner.

Comment: @user2661923 I misunderstood you earlier. Thanks for your comments.