# Prof says that $z^{a+b}=z^a z^b$ is not always true

Tags: complex-analysis

Our prof said that for $z, a,b \in \mathbb C$ we not always have $z^{a+b}=z^a z^b$.

I don't understand why. We have:

$$z^{a+b}=\exp(\ln(z)(a+b))=\exp(a \ln(z)+ b \ln(z))$$

According to our lecture we can write this as:
$$\exp(a \ln(z)) \cdot \exp(b \ln(z)) = z^a \cdot z^b$$

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: $\ln$ is not defined for all complex numbers! You have to choose a branch cut, and that's exactly when the problems begin.

Comment: Consider [Why $\sqrt{-1\cdot-1}\neq \sqrt{(-1)}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-cdot-1-neq-sqrt-12)

Comment: Well, no, $z^{a+b}=z^a z^b$ *is* true if you have fixed a choice of logarithm and $z$ is nonzero. What is *not* true in general is $z^a\cdot w^a=(zw)^a$ (for fixed choice of logarithm). Similarly $(z^a)^b=z^{ab}$ is not true in general

Comment: It is likely you have misinterpreted your professor. $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ is the *only* index law that carries over from the real numbers